# Slim php: How to handle CORS request without adding "options" routes

Tags: php, cors, slim

I have a slim application and I need to configure CORS, but when I check the [CORS chapter in the documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/cookbook/enable-cors.html), if I want to handle request methods, I have to add a new `options` route to every endpoint (excerpt from the docs):

```php
$app->add(function (Request $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): Response {
    $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
    $routingResults = $routeContext->getRoutingResults();
    $methods = $routingResults->getAllowedMethods();
    $requestHeaders = $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Headers');

    $response = $handler->handle($request);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', implode(',', $methods));
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $requestHeaders);

    // Optional: Allow Ajax CORS requests with Authorization header
    // $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    return $response;
});

// The RoutingMiddleware should be added after our CORS middleware so routing is performed first
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// The routes
$app->get('/api/v0/users', function (Request $request, Response $response): Response {
    $response->getBody()->write('List all users');

    return $response;
});

// Allow preflight requests
// Due to the behaviour of browsers when sending a request,
// you must add the OPTIONS method. Read about preflight.
$app->options('/api/v0/users', function (Request $request, Response $response): Response {
    // Do nothing here. Just return the response.
    return $response;
});
```

How can I avoid the pain of creating a new route everytime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging I was able to avoid adding a new handler for every route by creating a custom routing middleware. The idea is that it checks if the route resolves with the method sent in the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header, and if any, change the route callable to avoid calling the actual handler.

```php
class MyRoutingMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware
{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $request = $this->performRouting($request);
        if ($this->isPreflight($request)) {
            return new Response(200);
        }
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }

    protected function isPreflight(ServerRequestInterface $request): bool
    {
        return $request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS" &&
            $request->getHeaderLine("Access-Control-Request-Method") !== '';
    }

    protected function resolveRoutingResultsFromRequest(ServerRequestInterface $request): RoutingResults
    {
        $accessControlRequestMethod = $request->getHeaderLine("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        $isPreflight = $this->isPreflight($request);
        return $this->routeResolver->computeRoutingResults(
            $request->getUri()->getPath(),
            $isPreflight ? $accessControlRequestMethod : $request->getMethod()
        );
    }
}
```

And then I don't use the default RoutingMiddleware anymore :

```php
//add cors middleware globally
$app->add(function (Request $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): Response {
    $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
    $routingResults = $routeContext->getRoutingResults();
    $methods = $routingResults->getAllowedMethods();
    $requestHeaders = $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Headers');

    $response = $handler->handle($request);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', implode(',', $methods));
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $requestHeaders);

    // Optional: Allow Ajax CORS requests with Authorization header
    // $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    return $response;
});
// The routes
$app->get('/api/v0/users', function (Request $request, Response $response): Response {
    $response->getBody()->write('List all users');

    return $response;
});
// No need to add the $app->options(...) anymore !
//use custom routing middleware
$app->add(new MyRoutingMiddleware($app->getRouteResolver(), $app->getRouteCollector()->getRouteParser()));
```

**Update**

There is no CORS handling if an exception is thrown in your code (`HttpNotFoundException`, for instance) and that can be a problem, especially with `GET` requests (no preflight, but headers are checked), so I don't use the middleware provided in the slim documentation anymore but instead I created a factory that allows you to handle cors individually on your routes and handle error using the ErrorHandler (so your error output is still the same with or without CORS) :

```php
class CorsMiddlewareFactory
{
    /**
     * @var \Slim\Handlers\ErrorHandler
     */
    protected $errorHandler;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logErrorDetails;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logErrors;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $displayErrorDetails;

    /**
     * CorsMiddlewareFactory constructor.
     * @param \Slim\Handlers\ErrorHandler $errorHandler
     * @param bool $logErrorDetails
     * @param bool $logErrors
     * @param bool $displayErrorDetails
     */
    public function __construct(ErrorHandler $errorHandler, bool $logErrorDetails, bool $logErrors, bool $displayErrorDetails)
    {
        $this->errorHandler = $errorHandler;
        $this->logErrorDetails = $logErrorDetails;
        $this->logErrors = $logErrors;
        $this->displayErrorDetails = $displayErrorDetails;
    }


    public function create(array $origin = [], bool $allowCredentials = false, ?array $allowedHeaders = [], array $exposedHeaders = [])
    {
        $errorHandler = $this->errorHandler;
        $logErrorDetails = $this->logErrorDetails;
        $logErrors = $this->logErrors;
        $displayErrorDetails = $this->displayErrorDetails;
        return function (ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler)
        use ($allowCredentials, $allowedHeaders, $origin, $exposedHeaders, $errorHandler, $logErrorDetails, $logErrors, $displayErrorDetails): ResponseInterface {
            $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
            $routingResults = $routeContext->getRoutingResults();
            $methods = $routingResults->getAllowedMethods();
            if ($allowedHeaders === null) {
                $allowedHeaders = $request->getHeader('Access-Control-Request-Headers');
            }
            $isPreflight = $request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS" && !empty($request->getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method"));
            try {
                $response = $handler->handle($request);
            } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
                $response = ($errorHandler)($request, $exception, $displayErrorDetails, $logErrors, $logErrorDetails);
            }
            $headers=[
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> implode(',', $origin),
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> implode(',', $methods),
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> implode(',', $allowedHeaders),
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> $allowCredentials ? 'true' : 'false'
            ];
            foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
                if(!$response->hasHeader($name)){
                    $response=$response->withHeader($name,$value);
                }
            }
            if ($isPreflight && !$response->hasHeader('Access-Control-Exposed-Headers')) {
                $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Exposed-Headers', implode(',', $exposedHeaders));
            }
            return $response;
        };
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add your middlewares in your application (globally or on individual routes) :

```php
// Create Error Handler
$errorHandler = new ErrorHandler($app->getCallableResolver(), $$app->getResponseFactory());
// handle CORS requests
$corsFactory = new CorsMiddlewareFactory($errorHandler, false, true, true);
// allow all by default, YOLO !
$app->add($corsFactory->create(['*'], true, ['*'], ['*']));
// can be overriden on invidual routes as well
$app->get("/my/route",function($request,$response){
    return $response;
})->add($corsFactory->create(['http://google.fr'], false, [], []));
```

Comment: Have you also tested the CORS response header for NOT_FOUND and METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED errors?

Comment: Well the "OPTIONS" call is returning a 404 or a 415 in this case

Comment: I guess you mean I could return allowed methods for method not allowed cases. Not sure for not_found... @odan

Comment: Hi @odan, I updated my answer to handle user-generated `HttpException` (for non-preflighted Get requests). but I still don't understand what you meant regarding `NOT_FOUND` and `METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`.